# insert object into array based on dates oldest to newest

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, javascript-objects

I an array of objects. Each object has a date property and a string property. I also have an empty array. I cant figure out the logic to push the string based on date oldest to newest .

```
     const oldToNew = []
     for (const baseId in results[key][test]) {
            // log the array of objects
            //example [{string: 'test', date: '2019-03-04T10:36:37.206000Z'}, {string: 'test1', date: '2019-03-010T10:36:37.206000Z'}]
            console.log(results[key][test][baseId])
            results[key][test][baseId].forEach(element => {

            });
        }
     // I want the value to be [test, test1]
```

Comment: So is it that you want an array[string] of sorted items by date (oldest to newest)?

Comment: Yep @FrancisLeigh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort initial array with `sort` and then extract strings with `map`

something like this:

```
array.sort((a, b) => a.date < b.date).map(el => el.string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to compare the `date` property of each Object against the one before it - then use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return an Array of all the items '`string` properties.

*Update* no need to `parse` the date timestamp.

```js
const items = [{string: 'test4', date: '2019-03-04T10:36:37.206000Z'}, {string: 'test1', date: '2019-03-10T10:36:37.206000Z'}, {string: 'test2', date: '2019-03-09T10:36:37.206000Z'}, {string: 'test3', date: '2019-03-07T10:36:37.206000Z'}]

const strings = items
  .sort((a, b) => b.date > a.date)
  .map(({ string }) => string)

console.log(strings)
```

Comment: can we do something where there are more than 2 objects in the array

Comment: @Karam yes, do you have any stub data? this solution should work for any amount.

Comment: @Karam i have added two other items into the Array. if you have some data you would like to use, update your question with it :-)

Comment: you do not need to create new Date. ISO8601 is designed for lexicographical sort. 
so `'2007-01-17T08:00:00Z' < '2008-01-17T08:00:00Z' === true`